# sqlalchemy fails to connect to ms sql server

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Trying to connect to SQL server using SQLAlchemy with `pyodbc`(freeTDS) as the driver; The connections succeeds if I use `pyodbc` directly:

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=serverdsn;UID=user;PWD=password')
>>> crsr = conn.cursor()
>>> rows = crsr.execute("select @@VERSION").fetchall()
>>> print(rows)
[('Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.9248.28 Sep 12 2017 01:08:55 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation', )]
>>> crsr.close()
>>> conn.close()
```

But when I use SQLAlchemy, it fails with a mysterious error:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> e = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://user:password@serverdsn")
>>> with e.connect() as con:
...     rs = con.execute('select * from users')
...     for row in rs:
...         print(row)
...
```

Here is the full stack trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py",
>   line 1122, in _do_get
>       return self._pool.get(wait, self._timeout)   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/queue.py",
>   line 145, in get
>       raise Empty sqlalchemy.util.queue.Empty
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 2091, in connect
>       return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 90, in **init**
>       if connection is not None else engine.raw_connection()   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 2177, in raw_connection
>       self.pool.unique_connection, _connection)   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 2147, in _wrap_pool_connect
>       return fn()   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py",
>   line 328, in unique_connection
>       return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py",
>   line 766, in _checkout
>       fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py",
>   line 516, in checkout
>       rec = pool._do_get()   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py",
>   line 1138, in _do_get
>       self._dec_overflow()   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py",
>   line 66, in **exit**
>       compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 187, in reraise
>       raise value   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py",
>   line 1135, in _do_get
>       return self._create_connection()   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py",
>   line 333, in _create_connection
>       return _ConnectionRecord(self)   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py",
>   line 461, in **init**
>       self.**connect(first_connect_check=True)   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py",
>   line 661, in __connect
>       exec_once(self.connection, self)   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py",
>   line 246, in exec_once
>       self(*args, **kw)   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py",
>   line 256, in __call**
>       fn(*args, **kw)   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py",
>   line 1331, in go
>       return once_fn(*arg, **kw)   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py",
>   line 181, in first_connect
>       dialect.initialize(c)   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/connectors/pyodbc.py",
>   line 165, in initialize
>       super(PyODBCConnector, self).initialize(connection)   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/base.py",
>   line 1742, in initialize
>       super(MSDialect, self).initialize(connection)   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py",
>   line 256, in initialize
>       self.get_isolation_level(connection.connection)   File "/Users/purecarscomputer/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/base.py",
>   line 1735, in get_isolation_level
>       "tried views: %s; final error was: %s" % (views, err)) UnboundLocalError: local variable 'err' referenced before assignment

I've tried install and uninstall sqlalchemy and searched around on google, but not find a solution. Does anyone have similar problems and have a clue about what is happening?

OS information:

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.12.6
BuildVersion:   16G29
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the connection string I used to solve a connection problem with similar symptoms:

```
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# utilize existing odbc connection to create engine
params = urllib.quote_plus("DRIVER={}; SERVER=server; Database=database; UID=user; PWD=pw")
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
```

ref http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#pass-through-exact-pyodbc-string